# How to replace a value?

Tags: r, gsub

I have a column in a dataset where there are values referring to an economic amount. For example, 50.67 thousand euros, 78 thousand euros, 90 euros... All of them referring to thousand euros (the case where "euros" is written is obviously a mistake

I want to implement some code in R that allows me to remove the text that accompanies the numerical value and, instead, to have k€. For example 50.67 k€, 79 k€, 90 k€...

I have thought of doing it in the following way, however, in some records it says "thousand euros" or "euros" and therefore it cannot be done in a homogeneous way for all the values of a very long column.

```
Dataframe$column=gsub("\\thousand euros", "\\k€", as.character(Dataframe$column))
```

Any better idea?

Thank you

Comment: Do all the cases have some sort of string at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A two-step solution with `stringr` could be:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
Dataframe <- data.frame(column = c("50.67 thousand euros", "78 thousand euros", "90 euros"))


Dataframe %>% mutate(column = str_remove_all(column, "[^0-9.]"), column = paste(column, "k€"))
```

```
    column
1 50.67 k€
2    78 k€
3    90 k€
```

Comment: Thank you @Giulio Centorame ! I've tried to use your code and the output I get is 50.67 (k\200)    
78 (k\200)    
90 (k\200) instead of the one you have posted. I've searched for the reasons of this but I haven't found anything relevant

Comment: This is weird, what is your locale?

Comment: No worries! What was it due to?

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found it useful 

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot! Thank you for the help :)